# MySql query with conditional group by performance

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by

I have pretty simple table with about 1 000 000 rows and I want to retrieve some aggregate statistics from its. It is not analytic request, it is user data. I can retrieve the data with 3 separate queries each of which will be with specific where clause. But it will be THREE query to my DB server. And also I can do ONE query with **conditional ORDER BY** clause. But I never used such queries earlier on production. Should I expect some troubles with it?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER, fk_1 INTEGER, field_1 INTEGER, field_2 DATETIME);
 ... INSERT INTO t1 ... # 1 000 000 times

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 
WHERE fk_1 = <some_value> 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN (field_1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE (CASE WHEN field_2 > NOW() THEN 0 ELSE -1 END) END;
```

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, but you can use just one `CASE` statement with two `WHEN` clauses and an `ELSE`, instead of nesting them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use the `ID` in count like:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM t1 
WHERE fk_1 = <some_value> 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN (field_1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE (CASE WHEN field_2 > NOW() THEN 0 ELSE -1 END) END;
```

Comment: Does that really make a difference?

Comment: Yes. Performance-wise. or using an index or the key (id) itself.

Comment: in `InnoDB` engine should have a small improvement in speed

Comment: I think performance is mostly from having an index for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes, i totally agree... maybe he can show us a `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: I agree that they have the same execution plan. But since MySQL is now owned by Oracle. As far as I know and from what I understand this *MAY* have been an issue with Oracle where the query engine would treat them different, but I can’t confirm that just thought I would toss it out there for argument sake.